# Shrew Softly VPN under macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, installation, vpn, tunnel, macos-sierra

Hello how I can instal the software Shrew Softly VPN under macOS 10.12. 
Or which programme can import a .vpn file.

If I liked to instal Shrew Softly VPN I get the following announcement

```
    $ brew install shrewsoft-vpn-client
    $ Error: No available formula with the name "shrewsoft-vpn-client"
    $ ==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
    $ Error: No similarly named formulae found.
    $ ==> Searching taps...
    $ Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: I just tried the same. You need to tap the homebrew/boneyard. - brew tap homebrew/boneyard But then you will run into a tuntap and qt error. The thing with qt is the following error. - qt: This formula either does not compile or function as expected on macOS versions newer than El Capitan due to an upstream incompatibility. If I find any solution I'll let you know. Greetings

Comment: In macOS Sierra there seems to be pyqt4 package broken, however if you manage to install the client binaries (iked/ikec) you can use https://github.com/mejmo/mac-shrew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at my kb-website for compiling shrew soft vpn client from scratch.
http://kb.amft-it.de

It works with 10.12 and 10.13 too. Homebrew shrew don't work anymore, my solution works with orginal sources. Greetings

Comment: Please include necessary parts of your link contents in your answer.